# JCE convert unicode after save in my DB

Tags: mysql, jce, unicode

I added `&#128274;` in the source code of JCE. JCE convert it to .
The problem is after save in my database ist is a scratch characters `ðŸ”’`.
My question now is should I modyfy JCE (How?) or change the MySQL collation? It is now `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to what?.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39463134/2943403  There are a few different suggestions there.  If you manage to self-solve, please post your preferred adjustments.  Some of the more recent solutions talk about `blob` type columns.

Comment: And [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james) is incredibly wise, you can fairly well trust any of his posts to be awesome.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46655974/2943403  Just keep bouncing off of the links attached to my first commented link until you find something that works (and remember to upvote the good advice that you find).

Comment: @mickmackusa Thx, Blob works BUT what happens after joomla update or something else. I am not happy to change the data type.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: I suppose I should post the BLOB type advice as an answer rather than a comment.  What is a more last solution? Do you want to raise an issue in GitHub and see what the response looks like?

Comment: @mickmackusa before I close/answer this question I look for a solution without bloob. A issue on GitHub is a very good idea. Do you have a link for me? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STRIKE:
I found a better and simple solution:
just switch the collation of introtext to `utf8mb4_bin`

Comment: In reference to future versions, doesn't this structural adjustment have the same level of concern as using BLOB?

Comment: @mickmackusa I see it different. BLOB is changing the DB data structur and is defined as a binary data field. So I changed from text to binary typ. Collation is 'only' change the gramma for a sepecific languages. Of course the bin in utf8mb4_bin means binary  ;-)